# Custom order using orderBy in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have objects like this:

```
students = {name: 'Aa_Student', class: 'A_Class'},
           {name: 'Ab_Student', class: 'A_Class'},
           {name: 'Ac_Student', class: 'B_Class'},
           {name: 'Ba_Student', class: 'B_Class'},
           {name: 'Bb_Student', class: 'C_Class'},
           {name: 'Bc_Student', class: 'C_Class'}
```

Let's say the students object is shuffled.  I use ng-repeat to show the data.  I want to sort the objects in the custom order.

For example, I want to show the data like this:

```
  Name              Class
-----------------------------
Ac_Student         B_Class
Ba_Student         B_Class
Aa_Student         A_Class
Ab_Student         A_Class
Bb_Student         C_Class
Bc_Student         C_Class
```

So basically, I want to order by student's class, but it B_Class comes first, then A_Class, then C_Class. Also, I want to order by students name in alphabetic order.  How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy:customOrder">
    ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.customOrder = function(student) {
    $scope.students = $filter('orderBy')(student, function() {

    });
};
```

Comment: There are two ways to do this (1) Custom filter (2) Short your data at controller level

Comment: @dhavalcengg So I need to use filter?

Comment: Watch out for the typo in `$scope.studens` (missing a t)

Comment: use class for your orderBy

Comment: What should I write in the controller?

Comment: Check [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), there are good examples there.

Comment: @Gamb, but it is alphabetic order, right?

Comment: The "default" filtering in this case is alphabetic

Comment: @Gamb I don't want to order them in alphabetic order.  B_Class goes first.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hi you can create custom sort filter please see here http://jsbin.com/lizesuli/1/edit

html:

```
  <p ng-repeat="s in students |customSorter:'class'">{{s.name}} - {{s.class}} </p>
      </div>
```

angularjs filter:

```
app.filter('customSorter', function() {

  function CustomOrder(item) {
    switch(item) {
      case 'A_Class':
        return 2;

      case 'B_Class':
        return 1;

      case 'C_Class':
        return 3;
    }  
  }

  return function(items, field) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {    
      return (CustomOrder(a.class) > CustomOrder(b.class) ? 1 : -1);
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Comment: Hello there, `angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });` this code looks unnecessary to me, isn't it enough to say `var filtered = items;`

Answer (score 10):

Know this is old but may come in handy for others...

You could also create a simple custom sort function. "Not quite a filter":

```
$scope.customOrder = function (item) {
        switch (item) {
            case 'A_Class':
                return 2;

            case 'B_Class':
                return 1;

            case 'C_Class':
                return 3;
        }
    };
```

And then use like you wanted to:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy:customOrder">
...
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

to set the `orderBy` as a property of the objects just quote that property name within the markup:

```
ng-repeat="student in students |orderBy:'name' | orderBy:'class'"
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8IHqkndKL6lIKSe6PSCf?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but I want to order that B_Class goes first.  It's not alphabetic order.