# AngularJS orderBy a column containing a list

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

is it possible to use orderBy with something other than strings and numbers?

I have a list of customers and one of the columns contains an array of values (list of urls). I want to order by the url list, i.e. the first url in the list.

I thought the array would maybe be automatically converted to a string. I also tried using providerUrls[0] as orderBy criteria.

I know I could write my own sorting function but if there is a simple solution for this I would like to learn how to use it.

This is a reduced example of my code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p data-ng-click="sortBy = providerUrls; sortReverse = !sortReverse;">
                    URLs
                    <span data-ng-show="sortBy === providerUrls && !sortReverse">
                        <img src="arrow-down.svg"/>
                    </span>
                    <span data-ng-show="sortBy === providerUrls && sortReverse">
                        <img src="arrow-up.svg"/>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="provider in providerFilter = (providers | orderBy:sortBy:sortReverse) track by $index">
            <td>
                <p data-ng-repeat="url in provider.urls track by $index">
                    {{url}}
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My data structure:

```
var a = {
    providerId: "a",
    providerUrls: ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
    // more properties
};
// b and c similar

$scope.providers = [a, b, c];
```

Comment: what is your data structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom order using orderBy in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866492/custom-order-using-orderby-in-ng-repeat)